# SQL Server 2014 - Case statement not exiting

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I am having trouble writing a query to meet the following requirement.  One point if Cust_3_3_a through Cust_3_3_c is selected, or Cust_3_3_f through Cust_3_3_h is selected, or Cust_3_4_ is selected; Zero points if Cust_3_3_e is selected and Cust_3_4_ is not selected with value '-'.  Selected essentially means a the field has a value of a, b, c, etc.

Here is my test data and query.  I would expect with 'Cust_3_4_' set to '-', that 0 should return but 1 returns instead.  Is SQL not exiting the case when it hits 0 since the following check would return 1?  Thanks in advance.

```
declare @test table (QuestionKey nvarchar(100), ResponseValue nvarchar(100))
insert into @test (QuestionKey, ResponseValue)
values 
('Cust_3_3_a', ''),     ('Cust_3_4_', '-'),
('Cust_3_3_b', ''),     
('Cust_3_3_c', ''),     
('Cust_3_3_e', 'a'),        
('Cust_3_3_f', ''),     
('Cust_3_3_g', ''),     
('Cust_3_3_h', '')

select
max(case
        when (
                (t.questionkey = 'Cust_3_3_e' AND nullif(t.ResponseValue, '') IS NOT NULL)
                and (t.questionkey = 'Cust_3_4_' AND nullif(t.ResponseValue, '') != '-')
            ) then 1 
        when (
                (t.questionkey = 'Cust_3_3_e' AND nullif(t.ResponseValue, '') IS NOT NULL)
                and (t.questionkey = 'Cust_3_4_' AND nullif(t.ResponseValue, '') = '-')
            ) then 0
        when (
                t.questionkey BETWEEN 'Cust_3_3_a' AND 'Cust_3_3_c'
                OR t.questionkey BETWEEN 'Cust_3_3_f' AND 'Cust_3_3_h'
                OR t.questionkey = 'Cust_3_4_'
            ) and nullif(t.ResponseValue, '') IS NOT NULL then 1
        else 0
    end) as test1
from @test t
```

Comment: I believe you have a mistake in the first two cases. You are combining `(t.questionkey = 'Cust_3_3_e' AND...)` with `(t.questionkey = 'Cust_3_4_' AND...)` with `AND` instead of `OR`. As a result, those cases are always `false`.

Comment: @jmc Thanks, but I did try using OR in those two places which still result in the query returning one regardless of the value of 'Cust_3_4_'.

Comment: Once you switch those to `OR`, then the `1` result comes from `Cust_3_3_e` being `a`. To fix that, I think you'd need to fix `nullif(t.ResponseValue,'') IS NOT NULL` check for `Cust_3_3_e`. Based on your logic description, I think that check may actually need to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want but I think you are confused with how case statement works. In order for you to return 0 for `Cust_3_4_` where `ResponseValue != '-'`, you need to have an actual row with QuestionKey = `Cust_3_4_` and `ResponseValue != '-'` in your table (which you do not have in the above data set)

Also, you have applied `MAX` function outside your case so it will return you the maximum value 1 if any of the case condition returns 1. If you want the final result 0, you need to use `MIN` instead BUT please be aware that the `0` will be returned because of the following condition on `Cust_3_3_e`.  `Cust_3_4_` will have nothing to do with the `0`

```
declare @test table (QuestionKey nvarchar(100), ResponseValue nvarchar(100))
    insert into @test (QuestionKey, ResponseValue)
    values 
    ('Cust_3_3_a', ''),     ('Cust_3_4_', '-'),
    ('Cust_3_3_b', ''),     
    ('Cust_3_3_c', ''),     
    ('Cust_3_3_e', 'a'),        
    ('Cust_3_3_f', ''),     
    ('Cust_3_3_g', ''),     
    ('Cust_3_3_h', '')

    select * from @test
    order by 1 asc

    select *,case when QuestionKey IN ('Cust_3_3_a','Cust_3_3_b','Cust_3_3_c') THEN 1
                when QuestionKey = 'Cust_3_3_e' THEN 0
                when QuestionKey IN ('Cust_3_3_f','Cust_3_3_g','Cust_3_3_h') THEN 1 
                when QuestionKey  = 'Cust_3_4_' AND ResponseValue = '-' THEN 1
                when QuestionKey  = 'Cust_3_4_' AND ResponseValue <> '-' THEN 0
                end test1
    from @test
```

Comment: thanks for the response, so you mean with the MAX outside of the CASE that each case condition is evaluated within?  If that is true I will have to try a different approach due to all the possible scenarios that the ResponseValues can have to meet my requirement criteria.

Comment: Yes, because of MAX/MIN usage, it is returning only 1 row,  if you remove MAX/MIN(), it will return all 8 rows. I have edited my answer to show what you wanted.